# Can you attack from inside Rope Trick and vice versa?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, powers, actions, planes

Same question listed here, but for 5e.

[How much of a person or object must cross an extra-dimensional space's interface from inside, in order to attack a target outside of said space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109594/how-much-of-a-person-or-object-must-cross-an-extra-dimensional-spaces-interface)

From what I could find online, the wording of the spells has changed quite a bit, so I wanted to see if the findings in the previous question still hold true or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No, you can not attack from inside or vice versa

Rope trick specifically states (PHB, 272):

> Attacks and spells can't cross through the entrance into or out of the extradimensional space, but those inside can see out of it as if through a 3-foot-by-5-foot window centered on the rope.

### Using Miniatures

This is a bit of an easier case. The square you control and cast/attack from is the grid you are in. You can not take ownership of two separate grids unless you are a Large creature (or larger). This means that in order to cast from outside of the Rope Trick, you must absolutely leave the Rope Trick.

### Theatre of the Mind

This is a bit of a trickier proposition, but the same general idea applies from Miniatures. It may seem like you can simply reach outside of it, but the text of not being able to fire from within it suggests that such a workaround isn't possible. Combine that with how grids work and it is not a viable strategy to use it as a foxhole. It's more of a bolthole to escape from, not to attack from.

Comment: That makes it seem like you could still stick your hand out and cast fireball or stick your hand crossbow out and shoot it, so long as it is not going to hit the barrier first.

Comment: @bubbajake00 Added some more info as to why it's unlikely that this is allowed.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now, I was thinking of it just from a thematic perspective, not a mechanics one.  Thank you!