# In D&D 3.5, can a familiar be temporarily dismissed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, familiars

I am thinking of getting the Improved Familiar feat and obtaining a Hippogriff, but as a large creature, it could be hard to carry around especially when I am walking around in the city. Is there a (legal) way to temporarily put it somewhere else like the pocket dimension in 5e?

Comment: @From Yeah, there's probably a setting-specific solution, especially considering the relative commonality of exotic mounts, animal companions, summoned and called creatures, assorted simulacra, and other stuff, but having a general solution for when there isn't isn't a setting-specific solution (or in areas otherwise off limits to monsters) restricted  isn't a bad thing.

Comment: @From [Please do not answer in comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments).

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I was not answering the actual question, about temporarily hiding away a Large familiar, I was checking if it was indeed a problem in Terry's campaign world. As Hey I Can Chan remarked, the setting-agnostic question is a valid one and is the one I attempted to actually answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Try a *belt of many pockets*

A familiar that's bigger than Tiny like a [hippogriff](http://dndsrd.net/monstersHtoI.html#hippogriff) (*Monster Manual* 152 and that's available as a familiar through the feat [Improved Familiar](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#improved-familiar) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 200 and *Complete Warrior* 100)) won't fit into the extradimensional space created by the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell ***familiar pocket*** [univ] (*Spell Compendium* 88), but any size familiar can fit in a ***belt of many pockets*** (*Complete Arcane* 147–8) (11,000 gp; 1 lb.). The *belt*, in part, says

> [I]f the wearer has a familiar, any pouch [of the *belt*'s 64 pouches] can hold it [i.e. the wearer's familiar] **no matter what its size or weight**. The familiar has no need for food, water, or air while inside the pouch, but any other living creature of suitable size placed within a pocket has enough air for only 1 minute, after which it suffocates. (147 and emphasis mine)

This is, so far as I'm aware, the best way that the master can carry a hippogriff familiar (instead of the more common scenario of the hippogriff familiar carrying the master). There are alternatives, but they require taking a feat. For example, there's the [aforementioned](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/202032/8610) general feat **Lurking Familiar** (*Player's Handbook II* 80) that might work, and there's the general feat **Token Familiar** (*Dragon* #280 62) that likewise might suit:

> Your familiar can, on command, assume a small, inanimate form, much like a *figurine of wondrous power*…. The form can be any Diminutive, stone, hand-held object, typically a statuette of the familiar. In this form, the familiar does not require food or care, and it is easy to hide, but its powers are unavailable to you while in its statue form. The familiar in its statuette form still has a mind, but it cannot use any of its senses, special attacks, or special qualities. If its inanimate form is broken or destroyed, the familiar is slain. It can return to its normal form upon command.

These are all familiar specific, but your options don't have to be. Essentially, with the *belt*, you're paying for the familiar to survive in the extradimensional space for longer than 1 min., but if money is no object, you can have the familiar wear a [*necklace of adaptation*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#necklace-of-adaptation) (*DMG* 263) (9,000 gp; 0 lbs.) and a [*ring of sustenance*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#ring-of-sustenance) (*DMG* 230) (2,500 gp; 0 lbs.) and dump the familiar in a [*portable hole*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#portable-hole) (*DMG* 264) (20,000 gp; 0 lbs.) and forget about it. (Still, I'd check up on it occasionally lest its confinement make it ornery.) Likewise, a powerful enough wizard can just employ the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*polymorph*](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#polymorph) [trans] (*PH* 263) to turn the hippogriff familiar into something innocuous as the master roams around town.

---

***Note:** A PC in a campaign that I ran had a hippogriff familiar, and the player's solution to dungeoning with it was the* belt. *We found nothing better for the price.*

Comment: Clearly a better solution than mine; The belt explicitly Just Works (tm) and Token Familiar is a single feat with no prerequisites that doesn't require skill ranks in hiding and explaining why your robes are so huge...err, I meant Large.

Comment: I always thought it would be cool to have a bear companion that spent the majority of its time polymorphed as a mouse. You could carry it around and play with it like a mouse, but when combat started, simply throw the mouse at the enemy, and INSTANT BEAR. Unfortunately, such a thing would require extensive houseruling and/or resources.

Comment: @MooingDuck The only hard part is throwing it. That is, *dispel magic* says, "You automatically succeed on your dispel check against any spell that you cast yourself," so you could totally *baleful polymorph* a bear into a mouse and treat it like a mouse, and when combat occurs take a free action to drop it and cast *dispel magic* on it. *Poof.* Insta-bear. (If you threw the beouse first it'd probably some kind of attack, and a smart enemy'll step on any little creature a wizard throws, likely before you could dispel the *baleful polymorph*.) By the way, I suggest training that bear *a lot.*

Comment: A Lycanthrope has the Shapechanger subtype, so it can cancel Baleful Polymorph with a standard action. But a bear can't be a lycanthrope, so plans of a werebear bear are hopeless. A Druid with Leadership, no Animal Companion, and a werebear cohort roleplaying as a bear?

Answer (score 3):

With a **Necklace of Adaptation** (*Dungeon Master's Guide* page 263) to allow them to breath you can put them in a **Bag of Holding** (*Dungeon Master's Guide* page 248) or a **Portable Hole** (*Dungeon Master's Guide* page 264).  You'd need a Type III Bag of Holding at minimum to fit a Hippogriff, possibly a Type IV, so this solution is pretty expensive. (9,000 gp for the Necklace of Adaptation, and either 7,400 gp or 10,000 gp for the Bag of Holding, or 20,000 gp for the Portable Hole).

A somewhat cheaper solution to the problem (if not a direct answer to the question) is the **Shrink Collar** (*Arms and Equipment Guide* page 80) which reduces its wearer to small size.  It can explicitly be used on animal companions.  Though this still isn't the cheapest at 10,000 gp.

Comment: (*Nitpick:* A *bag of holding* is "about 2 feet by 4 feet in size." Assuming the opening is on the 2-ft. side, it'll be tough to fit the Large hippogriff in it. The spell *reduce animal* won't work on the hippogriff as it's a magical beast not an animal. The *shrink collar* probably doesn't have a duration, but the text isn't as clear as it should be. Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109594/8610) about straddling dimensions.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to keep a non-tiny familiar hidden (see the Spell Compendium for the Familiar Pocket spell for tiny creatures), but there is a way to keep a familiar out of sight - sort of. This would be a bit silly, but working by RAW. Get the Combat Familiar feat at level 1 or 3, get your Hide skill as high as possible, then at level 6 get the [Lurking Familiar feat](https://realmshelps.net/charbuild/feat/Lurking_Familiar):

> ### Lurking Familiar
>
> Your familiar hides within the folds of your robe or takes cover
> behind you as your opponents close in. When it moves to attack, its
> sudden appearance might catch your foe by surprise.
>
> **Benefit**: If your
> familiar occupies your square, it gains cover against all attacks. As
> a consequence, it can make a Hide check to avoid your foe's notice. If
> your familiar then leaves your space to attack an opponent, it gains
> the normal benefit for attacking from a hidden position.

How would a Large creature hide within the robes of a Medium creature? **Don't know**. But this is RAW territory, so logic and reason hold no sway here.

There's also the old evergreen of the [Invisibility spell](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/invisibility.htm). Keep your familiar outside the city until you have found a place to store it, then Invis it and yourself and fly to that place. If you get there within (Level) minutes, you got away with it.

It can't physically fit somewhere? Cast [Reduce Person](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/reducePerson.htm) on yourself, then Share Spell it with your familiar.

Comment: Talking about invisibility, would a ring of invisibility for the familiar work? It seems to be a permanent invisibility until it attacks.

Comment: @TerryWindwalker The invisibility granted by a [*ring of invisibility*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#ring-of-invisibility) is as the spell so the duration is 3 min.